# I'm having a hard time fixing an overflowing image

Tags: css

I was learning how to make a recipe-app on youtube with Javascript, then I finished it, but there is a problem, the app I was learning how to make has a function that when you click on an image it shows the recipe info but the info screen was too big for my pc, like it overflows and I couldn't click on the button (which is an X) to close the image and the person I was watching to learn on how to make this app managed to put a scroll bar on the images while I did EVERYTHING he did, the scroll bar didn't show up for me. and when I tried to adjust the size of the image info it only affected the sides while the top and bottom were unaffected (the sides were too thin and that made the image and text compressed and that gave it a bad apparence).

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Recipes App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div class="mobile-container">
            <header>
                <input type="text" id="search-term" />
                <button id="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </header>
            <div class="fav-container">
    <h3>Favorite Meals</h3>
    <ul class="fav-meals" id="fav-meals"></ul>
        </div>
            <div class="meals" id="meals"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-container hidden" id="meal-popup">
        <div class="popup">
            <button id="close-popup" class="close-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
            <div class="meal-info" id="meal-info"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Here is the CSS/Style Code (the popup part is the image that overflows):

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFDEE9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFDEE9 0%, #B5FFFC 100%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.mobile-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #3333331a;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

header input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

header button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.fav-container {
    background-color: #cc444494;
    padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.fav-meals {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}   

.fav-meals li { /* O position: relative; coloca o botão perto da foto da receita */
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 75px;
}

.fav-meals li .clear { /* Esse é para o botão de deletar as receitas da lista de favoritos */
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5rem;
    right: -0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.fav-meals li:hover .clear { /* O :hover é para quando você passar o cursor do mouse em cima de algo */
    opacity: 1;
} 

.fav-meals li img {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #3333331a;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

.fav-meals li span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 75px;
}

.meal {
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #3333331a;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.meal-header {
    position: relative;
}

.meal-header .random {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.meal-header img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}

.meal-body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.meal-body h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

.meal-body .fav-btn {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cecaca;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.meal-body .fav-btn.active {
    color: crimson;
}

.popup-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.popup-container.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 2rem;
    max-width: 100vh;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.popup .close-popup {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
}

.meal-info h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML, and if applicable, CSS. We cannot help you otherwise. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In `.popup`  you have two `max-width` rules - I believe one of them is meant to be `max-height`, because height have to be specified along with `overflow: auto`.

Nonetheless, a useful suggestion - most tutorial videos have a link to source code. You can look there if something else is missed and not shown in the video.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to fix it. the problem was that the max-width: 100vh; line was supposed to be max-height: 100vh; instead but i didn't notice it.